# CentOS 5.11: yum installs, but packages remain missing

Tags: yum, centos5, rpm

I'm trying to figure out a very strange problem with `yum` on a fairly old CentOS 5.11 VPS using DirectAdmin.

Executing the following command suggests the `telnet` package is installed:

```
# yum install telnet
...
Installed:
  telnet.x86_64 1:0.17-41.el5
```

However, `telnet` is still missing:

```
# which telnet
/usr/bin/which: no telnet in (/root/local/node/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/share/adt-bundle/tools:/root/share/adt-bundle/platform-tools)
```

My version of Yum is 3.2.22.

Perhaps a hint of what is going wrong is that I appear to have different versions of `rpm` installed somehow. If I try to verify my RPM database, my database version appears invalid:

```
# rpm --version
RPM version 4.3.3
# rpm --verify telnet
rpmdb: Program version 4.2 doesn't match environment version
error: db4 error(22) from dbenv->open: Invalid argument
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 - Invalid argument (22)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
package telnet is not installed
```

If I rebuild the RPM database using the following command:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rpm/__db* && rpm --rebuilddb
```

Yum gives a similar error, but complaining about a newer version:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
rpmdb: Program version 4.3 doesn't match environment version
error: db4 error(-30974) from dbenv->open: DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 -  (-30974)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
```

Removing the `/var/lib/rpm/__db*` files gets Yum past this again, but installed packages still appear to be missing.

I get the feeling that Yum is somehow misconfigured or that I have two different versions of RPM. What can I do to diagnose the problem to ultimately work to a resolution?

Comment: Interesting! Does a `yum clean all` followed by `yum update rpm` alter anything? Sounds like the version of RPM isn't in step with Yum, so they're writing incompatible versions of the database? I also found a note saying to check that `rpm`, `rpmq`, `up2date` and `rhnsd` are not running before removing the `__db*` files.

Comment: None of those processes are running (`rpmq`, `up2date` and `rhnsd` are not on the path), and `yum clean all && yum update rpm` finishes with "No Packages marked for Update". I recall having at some point reinstalled yum directly via RPM, and don't believe I ever checked if it worked at all, so you're probably right about not being in step. Another hint is that both `librpmdb-4.3.so` and `librpmdb-4.4.so` are present in `/usr/lib64/`.

Comment: That sounds like it could well be the problem: can you move one of the `librpmdb` libraries out of the way and try the commands?

Comment: I've moved all `librpm*-4.3.so` into a backup directory, but deleting the RPM databases and rebuilding them still produces the "rpmdb: Program version 4.3 doesn't match environment version" in Yum. It appears that the current rpm binary is still 4.3.3 as this is what `rpm --version` gives. Perhaps everything would fix itself if I can get RPM 4.4 installed correctly?

Comment: I found some additional 4.3 libraries in `/var/lib`, and removing those breaks RPM. Executing RPM from the terminal gives "rpm: error while loading shared libraries: librpm-4.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", and while Yum doesn't give any errors, it still doesn't install packages and behaves as before.

Comment: I've grabbed the [rpm-4.4.2.3](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/5.11/x86_64/RPMS/rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64.html) and tried installing it using `rpm -ivh rpm-[...].rpm && updatedb`. While that works (and the correct version is listed in `rpm -qa`), `rpm --version` still gives 4.3.3. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's odd, although the `updatedb` command I think is for mlocate (at least on my system). It sounds like something is still loaded - simple (horrible) solution could be a reboot?

Comment: I've tried a reboot; unfortunately nothing changed.